# ASP.NET chart control issue, background not transparent

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, web

How can I make the white section for this chart transparent, 
[image]

Comment: Use the background color of the chart same as your background?

Comment: What you make for that put something?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I  got;

```
<asp:Chart>
   <BorderSkin BackColor="Transparent" PageColor="Transparent" />
</asp:Chart>
```

in your case this will be

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 100px; top: 50px; position: absolute; background-color: transparent " BackColor="Transparent" PageColor="Transparent" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackImageTransparentColor="Silver" BorderlineColor="Transparent" Width="410px">
   <BorderSkin BackColor="Transparent" PageColor="Transparent" />
</asp:Chart>
```

Comment: done that:(,            <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" 
                style="z-index: 1; left: 100px; top: 50px; position: absolute; background-color: transparent " 
                BackColor="Transparent" PageColor="Transparent" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                BackImageTransparentColor="Silver" BorderlineColor="Transparent" Width="410px">

Comment: Have you actually viewed it in a browser. Maybe the page colour is white and although it is transparent, the page behind it happens to be white too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on i hope it's work:

```
  <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">

        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie" XValueMember="relatedcity" 
                YValueMembers="state_id">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="Transparent">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

Use chart Area to make it Transparent Background.

Answer (score 1):

Set the chart and chartarea BackColor = "Transparent"

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" >
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Text="Bubble Chart"></asp:Title>
    </Titles>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend LegendStyle="Table" Docking="Bottom" IsDockedInsideChartArea="false" Name="Legend1"></asp:Legend>
    </Legends>
</asp:Chart>
```